Example of an infinite descending sequence of transitive subgroups with trivial intersection
I'm looking for an example of a set $X$ of size $\ge 2$, together with an infinite descending sequence $G = G_0\supset G_1\supset G_2\supset\cdots$ such that each $G_i$ is a transitive subgroup of $\text{Sym}(X)$, $G_0$ is finitely generated, but $\cap_{i\ge 1}G_i = 1$.
Is something like this possible?
Note that if we allow $G$ to act non-faithfully on $X$, then you can have examples like $G = \mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{Z}/3$, $G_i = 2^i\mathbb{Z}$.
I'm also interested in conditions on $G,X,G_i$ that would prevent such a possibility.

I haven't thought this through, so I won't write an answer yet, but I was thinking of $X={\mathbb Z}$. Let $x$ be the infinite cycle $n \mapsto n+1$, let $y_k$ be the transposition $(0,2^k)$ for $k \ge 0$ and $G_k= \langle x,y_k\rangle$.

@DerekHolt That won't satisfy the condition $\cap_{i\ge 1}G_i = 1$, will it?

@JeremyRickard Yes you are right! I hadn't given it enough thought.

Perhaps we could replace $G_1$ by $G_1^{(0,1)}$ and then replace $G_2^{(0,1)}$ by $G_2^{(0,1)(0,2)}$, etc.?

It should be replace $G_2^{(0,1)}$ by $G_2^{(0,1)(1,2)}$, $G_3^{(0,1)(1,2)}$ by $G_3^{(0,1)(1,2)(2,4)}$, etc. I have proved that this works, but since the question has now been answered by Moishe Kohan, I won't try and write down the proof.

Yes, this is possible even in finitely generated groups $G$. Let $G$ be a residually finite finitely generated group and $H< G$ be a profinitely dense subgroup, i.e. for every finite quotient $f: G\to F$, $f(H)=f(G)=F$. Define $X:= G/H$ with the action of $G$ by left multiplication. Profinite density of $H$ implies that every finite index subgroup of $G$ acts transitively on $X$. In order to ensure faithfulness of the $G$-action on $X$ one needs $H$ to satisfy a form of malnormality condition: For every $h\in H\setminus \{1\}$ there exists $g\in G$ such that $ghg^{-1}\notin H$. (For the lack of a better name, I will say that such $H$ is SQB-malnormal.)
Such subgroups $H$ one can construct, I think, in all finiteley generated matrix groups $G$ which are not virtually solvable, following the method of Margulis and Soifer, see my answer here. I checked this in the case when $G$ is a free noncyclic group (a similar proof works for all discrete subgroups of rank 1 Lie groups). But it is a bit long. Here is a sketch: Enumerate homomorphisms from $G$ to finite groups (there are countably many of these). For every such homomorphism $f: G\to F$ and every $k\in F$ pick some $g_{f,k}\in f^{-1}(k)\in G$. Now, and this is a difficult part requiring a ping-pong argument,  one finds an SQB-malnormal subgroup $H< G$ which is freely generated by conjugates of the elements of the form $g_{f,k}$. This is the required subgroup.
Now, the sequence of subgroups $G_i$ consists of all finite index normal subgroups. Residual finiteness of $G$ means that their intersection is trivial.
This is a type of an argument that Margulis and Soifer are using as a step in their construction of maximal subgroups.
Edit. 1. To relate SQB-malnormality to faithfulness of the action of $G$ on $X$, note that for every $g\in G- H$, $gH\ne H$, i.e. $g$ acts nontrivially on $X$. Now, if $h\in H$, we need to find $g\in G$ such that $hgH\ne gH$, i.e. $g^{-1}hg\notin H$ ($h$ acts nontrivially on $X$ if and only if such $g$ exists). But the existence of such $g$ is exactly what SQB-malnormality guarantees.

Regarding transitivity: Let $G_1< G$ be a normal finite index subgroup. Transitivity of $G_1$-action on $X=G/H$ means that for every $g\in G$ there is $g_1\in G_1$ and $h\in H$ such that $g=g_1h$, i.e. that $G=G_1H=HG_1$ (since $G_1$ is normal in $G$). But the equality $G=HG'_1$ exactly means that the projection of $H$ to $F=G/G_1$ is the entire $F$. This is the profinite density condition.

As for conditions on $G$ when such a sequence does not exist, take any finitely generated abelian group $G$. Then every transitive faithful $G$-action must be simply-transitive. Hence, no proper subgroup of $G$ will act transitively on $X$.


